# how to use PrinterStateReason in Java?

Tags: java

Need a help. I don't know how to use `PrinterStateReason` to giving printer. we can call `PrinterStateReason` in this way

`PrinterStateReason pr =PrinterStateReason.OUTPUT_AREA_FULL;`

but I want to check the state of a giving printer is it possible with `PrinterStateReason`?

example :

```
PrintService[] pservices =PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null);
log.info("Printer Attrbute"+ pservices .getAttributes().toArray());
```

this will list down all print which are available in the giving network. I don't know how to use `PrinterStateReason`  in the same way?

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16035739/how-to-access-the-status-of-the-printer)

Comment: Yes. i published that question too. PrinterStateReason  contain 33 instance . I'm confused why can't we access one buy one. example i only need to check MEDIA_JAM using PrinterStateReason . Is it possible?