# How can i know the status of the specific printer in java

Tags: java, printing, status

Is there a way to find the below  properties from the printer ?

**Printer is installed or not**
**Printer is connected or not**
**Paper out or any error**

I used `javax.print API`, this help me to print a documents in the printer and it list down 4 attributes

```
printer-is-accepting-jobs: accepting-jobs

printer-name: myPrinter

queued-job-count: 0

color-supported: not-supported
```

But I don't know how to get the above peroperties from the printer API. I found that there is something called PrinterStateReason, But I don't know how to get the `PrinterStateReason` for my printer. I have tried getting it from the attributeset. But I couldn't.

Please help me on the above issues

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the status of the printer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16035739/how-to-access-the-status-of-the-printer "How to access the status of the printer?")

Answer (score -1):

Use javax.print. For details look [here](http://www.ehow.co.uk/how_6786796_check-printer-availability-using-java.html)